# NSManagedObjectContext doesn't save or fetch in custom class different than UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiviewcontroller, nsmanagedobject

I've been using the UIViewController to manage Core Data. Now i want to move and better organize the code, but realize that NSManagedObjectContext only works properly in my UIViewController class.

Trying to save or fetch values in other class gets an unsolved error...

```
if ( ([context hasChanges]) ) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ( (![context save:&error]) ) {
        return true ;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@, %@, %@", error, [error userInfo],[error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]  );
        return false ;
    }
} else return false ;
```

Getting ... " Unresolved error (null), (null), (null), (null) "

i thought was a problem getting the context ...

```
 - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
```

}

But still doesn't work if I pass the NSManagedObjectContext object from the ViewController and saving or fetching from this class. So, needs to " [context save:&error] " in the UIViewController to work.

I need to access the NSManagedObjectContext from custom classes to organize the code...
What's the point here , any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

`[context save:&error]` is working just fine in your code. That is why the error is null. The problem is merely that your logic is backward: you are going to the "false" branch when in fact the save succeeded.

Comment: Sorry... was a mistake I wish was just it ... edited to : if ( ![context save:&error] )

Comment: But your `NSLog` still isn't generating any error, so there is no reason for me to believe there is an error. It seems more likely that `context` is `nil`. Is it? That should be easy for you to find out.

Comment: Easy ? I ‘m two days trying to figure it out ... if i pass the context from the UiViewController doesn’t work. Only saving or fetching from ViewController . Maybe easy for you, doesn’t mean easy for everyone

Comment: Ok, edited to show the code as it is. The context is not nil.

Comment: in fact ... before saving, this is true : if ( ([context hasChanges]) ) { ...

Comment: OK, that's great. So my answer still stands. You've got the `![context save:&error])` backwards and that's the problem. Remove the `!` sign and all will be will. You'll discover that you are saving just fine, and you will return `true`, and that's that.

Comment: oh man, so stupid, got it ... I think i need holidays. THanks so much,

Comment: Yes, it's much better when you show your _real_ code. My answer was initially sort of a guess (based on the fact that there was no error being logged), but when you show the real code it is clear what's going on.

Comment: I know ... i tried to quit off unnecessary code ...  Cheers matt!!!